# Hyperref generates a wrong reference in the Bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, hyperref, citing, natbib

I have a citation in my caption and it should also appear in the List of figures. However in the bibliography hyperref generates a reference of this citation to the previous chapter of the LOF. For instance:

```
Chapter 1 |
Chapter 2  |
Figure -> caption:(\cite{Hawking})
Chapter 3 |
LOF |
BIB 
[1] Hawking  2.1 3
```

I do not want the last reference (3) in my Bibliography. Can someone help?
Thank you in advance

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=normal,twoside,parskip,bibliography=totoc,index=toto,final,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[bookmarks,          
              bookmarksopen=true,
                  colorlinks=true,
                  linkcolor=black,
                  pdfpagelayout = TwoPageRight,
                  citecolor=blue,
                  urlcolor=blue,
                  backref,
                  linktocpage]{hyperref}    

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\chapter{Two}

\section{TwoPointOne}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption \cite{Hawking1998}}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Three}

\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LOF}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}   

\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the backrefs in the list of figures locally:

```
\backrefsetup{disable}
\listoffigures
\backrefsetup{enable}
```